Is it normal to have negative Baseline Stem Water Potential (BSWP) values?
I calculated the VPD (Vapor Pressure Deficit) from the known equation. Then I used an equation to calculate the Baseline Stem Water Potential (BSWP). The strange thing is that the values I get are negative!!! Bear in mind that BSWP and VPD, as I read in literature, are in kPa. Is this normal? I mean is it normal to get negative values in BSWP ?
